# Signal handling behavior is reset to default with sigaction

Tags: c

I have a piece of code like this:

```
struct sigaction sigtstp_act;

sigtstp_act.sa_handler = sigtstp_handler;
sigemptyset(&sigtstp_act.sa_mask);
sigtstp_act.sa_flags = 0;

sigaction(SIGTSTP, &sigtstp_act, NULL);
```

This is the code for the hanlder:

```
void sigtstp_handler(int signo) {
    printf("SIGTSTP received. Going to new file...\n");
    fclose(f);
    goto_next_file();
    return;
}
```

and this is the `go_to_next_file` function:

```
void go_to_next_file() {
  //Increments file_number, opens a new file to write to.
  file_number  += 1;

  char filename[32];
  snprintf(filename, sizeof(char) * 32, "%i.txt", file_number);

  f = fopen(filename, "w");
  //Check if opening a new file was successful.
  if (f == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

But after the first time SIGTSTP happens, my handler is removed and default behavior is restored. 
How can I install my handler permanently through sigaction()?

Comment: Can you post the code to your handler?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid calling unsafe functions inside your signal handler. It results in undefined behaviour, as mentioned in the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html):

> If a signal interrupts the execution of an unsafe function, and
>   handler either calls an unsafe function or handler terminates via a
>   call to longjmp() or siglongjmp() and the program subsequently calls
>   an unsafe function, then the behavior of the program is undefined.

You can see a list of safe functions in the manual. Most of your functions is not in the list. The best approach is setting a `volatile` flag inside the signal handler, and handling everything inside the main program execution.